# Jms session.recovery meaning

Tags: java, session, jms, messaging, recovery

I am investigating the JMS API

I misunderstand the following method meaning:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html#recover--

> **void recover()
>         throws JMSException**
>   Stops message delivery in this session, and restarts message delivery with the oldest unacknowledged message. All
>   consumers deliver messages in a serial order. Acknowledging a received
>   message automatically acknowledges all messages that have been
>   delivered to the client.
>
> Restarting a session causes it to take the following actions:
>
> Stop message delivery Mark all messages that might have been delivered
>   but not acknowledged as "redelivered" Restart the delivery sequence
>   including all unacknowledged messages that had been previously
>   delivered. Redelivered messages do not have to be delivered in exactly
>   their original delivery order. Throws: JMSException - if the JMS
>   provider fails to stop and restart message delivery due to some
>   internal error. IllegalStateException - if the method is called by a
>   transacted session.

[in another](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncfw/index.html) doc written:

> If you use a queue or a durable subscription, you can use the
>   Session.recover method to stop a nontransacted session and restart it
>   with its first unacknowledged message. In effect, the session’s series
>   of delivered messages is reset to the point after its last
>   acknowledged message. The messages it now delivers may be different
>   from those that were originally delivered, if messages have expired or
>   if higher-priority messages have arrived. For a nondurable
>   TopicSubscriber, the provider may drop unacknowledged messages when
>   its session is recovered.

But it still unclear what happens.
Maybe real use case can help to understand.